# Angular ngFor - TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'OptionItem'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I think I may be slowly going mad today but hear me out. I am making an Angular component that takes an `Input()` of either a string array or custom object array and then applies this to an HTML select menu options using `ngFor` with some logic to determine if the `Input()` is a string array or not.

Here is my component, notice how I have introduced types at the top of my component:

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

type OptionValue = Readonly<{
  title: string;
  value: string;
}>;

type OptionItem = OptionValue | string;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css'],
  template_: `
    <select *ngIf="options?.length">
      <!-- for simple string arrays -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="isStingSelect">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [attr.value]="option">
          {{ option }}
        </option>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- for obj arrays -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="!isStingSelect">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [attr.value]="option.value">
           {{ option.title }}
        </option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>`
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() options!: OptionItem[];

  isStingSelect = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (typeof this.options[0] === 'string') {
      this.isStingSelect = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now in another component, I add to use my custom select component and pass through the following data:

This is the object array I create in the component template file:

```
dataOptions = [
  {
    value: 'www.some-url.com',
    title: 'Simple'
  }, 
  {
    value: 'www.some-other-url.com',
    title: 'Live Monitor'
  }
];
```

and here I am using my custom select component in the template with the data:

```
<app-select [options]="dataOptions"></app-select>
```

This produces the following error:

```
TS2551: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'OptionItem'. Did you mean 'valueOf'?
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

10     <option *ngFor="let option of options" [attr.value]="option.value">
```

For some reason, my `OptionValue`, `OptionItem` and `OptionItem[]` are working correctly? I have been looking at this for some time and can't see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that this is the default [template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#overview-of-template-type-checking) performed by Angular and complain that `OptionItem` could be a `string` type that doesn't have a `value` property.

Even if you use a variable to check whether it is a `string` type or not, this is run-time but not compilation time. Hence, this will not overcome the type-checking issue.

Think that what you can achieve is combining both `<ng-container>` handle for the different type into one. And implement the methods to check the `option` type and return the respective value based on type.

Rendering items in the `*ngFor` directive by calling method each could impact the performance if there is a huge set of elements. A recommendation would be to implement the [`trackBy`](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction#description) in the `*ngFor` directive so that DOM elements will not get destroyed each time and re-render when there is an element added/removed.

```
<select *ngIf="options?.length">
  <ng-container>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options; trackBy: trackByFn" [attr.value]="getOptionValue(option)">
      {{ getOptionLabel(option) }}
    </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

```
getOptionLabel(option: OptionItem) {
  return typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.title;
}

getOptionValue(option: OptionItem) {
  return typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.value;
}

trackByFn = (index: number, option: OptionItem) => {
  this.getOptionValue(option);
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmtkda?file=src/select/select.component.ts)